# Register an entity class dynamically without recreating the session factory

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity class which I want to register dynamically.
Can we register an entity class dynamically without recreating the session factory in run time using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No.

The bootstrap process creates the Metadata and passes it to the SessionFactory upon instantiation. For this reason, you can not add entities dynamically to a SessionFactory, meaning that you need to recreate it from scratch.

However, the SessionFactory initialization can be done programmatically so you can recreate it whenever you have new entities that need to be registered.